# Delete a row in a dataframe and get a dataframe back

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to "subset" this dataframe and remove the second row using the rowname

```
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(rnorm(5))
rownames(MyDataFrame) 
#"1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  

myDataFrame[-2,]
# 0.2706859  0.9708845  0.7559821 -0.2063368
```

I want to be able to get the results above, but in a data frame form (with the original row names). I looked around and it seems the way to select by rowname is to use the which function, but I'm not sure how it would work in this context.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you use `-2` you are not removing the row with name "2" but removing the second row. If you wanted to use rownames, you would have to do `myDataFrame[!rownames(myDataFrame) %in% "2", , drop = FALSE]` or `myDataFrame[-match("2", rownames(myDataFrame)), , drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an argument `drop = FALSE`.

```
> mydf[-2, , drop = FALSE]
    rnorm(5)
1  1.9602780
3  0.1078827
4 -0.8517422
5 -0.8300695
```